# Fullscreen Dialog Fragment not showing correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I've got two problems:
In my app I have an activity with the appbar and a recycler view.
When i click an option of the floating action menu it displays a Fullscreen Dialogfragment but for some reason the dialog is not showing correctly (not totaly fullscreen).

Here is the result 
[dialogfragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj2fC.png)
Also when I click the close button of the Dialog it closes not only the dialog, but the activity as well, and goes to the previous activity.
What should I do. I am beginning Android.
also I want to establish a margin for the cardview (left and right)

Here is my code

**Result_contract.java**

public class Result_contract extends AppCompatActivity  implements

FragmentActions{
    String TAG="Result_contract";

```
private boolean first_time= true;
private List<Contract>lista_contratos;
private FloatingActionsMenu fabm;
private RecyclerView recycler;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager lManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result_contract);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Contratos");//Set title

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);//Enable Back button
    fabm= (FloatingActionsMenu)findViewById(R.id.menu_fab);

    View fab_buscar =  findViewById(R.id.accion_buscar);
    fab_buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showSearchDialog();

        }
    });
    View fab_formulario =  findViewById(R.id.accion_formulario);
    fab_formulario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showDetailsDialog(0);
        }
    });


    recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reciclador);
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    lManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(lManager);

    //todo REMOVER ESTO
   //SearchContractTask buscar = new SearchContractTask(Contract_query_instance.getInstance().getContractQuery());
    //buscar.execute();
    SearchContractTask buscar = new SearchContractTask(null);
    buscar.execute();


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; goto parent activity.
            this.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void showDetailsDialog(int position) {
    fabm.collapse();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

    Fragment fragment=new Dialog_contract();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();
    args.putInt("position",position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    transaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment,"dialog_contract").addToBackStack(null).commit();



}

@Override
public void showSearchDialog() {
    fabm.collapse();

}

@Override
public void load_data() {

}

public class SearchContractTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    Connection cnx;
    Models models;
    Contract_query query;
    public SearchContractTask(Contract_query query) {
        super();
        cnx = Connection.getConnection();
        models= Models.getInstance();
        this.query=query;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        lista_contratos=Contract_list.getInstance().getList_contract();
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        if (lista_contratos!=null) {
            adapter = new Contract_adapter(lista_contratos);
            recycler.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
        else {
            //TODO  MOSTRAR UN MENSAJE DE QUE NO EXISTEN FILAS EN LA CONSULTA
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {

    }



}
@Override public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (fabm.isExpanded()) {

            Rect outRect = new Rect();
            fabm.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);

            if(!outRect.contains((int)event.getRawX(), (int)event.getRawY()))
                fabm.collapse();
        }
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fabm.isExpanded()) {

            fabm.collapse();
        }
    else{
        finish();

    }
    //super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

**activity_reult_contract.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.ernesto.apptranscargo.Result_contract">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_result_contract" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:fab_labelStyle="@style/Etiquetas"
        app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:fab_addButtonSize="normal"

        app:fab_labelsPosition="left">

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/accion_formulario"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fab_colorNormal="?attr/colorAccent"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_tablet"
            app:fab_size="normal"
            app:fab_title="Formulario" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/accion_buscar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fab_colorNormal="?attr/colorAccent"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_search"
            app:fab_size="normal"
            app:fab_title="Nueva Búsqueda" />

    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_result_contract.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/reciclador"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

**Dialog_contract.java**

```
public class Dialog_contract extends DialogFragment implements DialogActions {

    public static final String TAG = "fragment_dialog";

    private TabLayout Tabs;
    private Form_contract_detail fragment_detalles;
    private Form_contract_observation fragment_obseration;
    private Fragment fragment_observation;
    View view_contract;
    ViewPager pager;
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    String title="Detalles  ";
    int cantidad;

    public Dialog_contract(){
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void  Dismiss()
    {
        getDialog().dismiss();

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        cantidad= Contract_list.getInstance().getList_contract().size();
        view_contract=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_contract, container, false);

        pager=(ViewPager)view_contract.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter= new Dialog_contract_adapter(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(),Contract_list.getInstance().getList_contract().size());

       toolbar = (Toolbar) view_contract.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
        }
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        int position=getArguments().getInt("position", -1);
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        pager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
        //pager.setPageTransformer(true,new DepthPageTransformer() );
        pager.setCurrentItem(position);

        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                updateTitle();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });


        updateTitle();
        return view_contract;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dialog_contract_menu, menu);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_next) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
           updateTitle();
            return true;
        } else if (id==R.id.action_previous)
        {

            pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
           updateTitle();
            return true;
        }

        else if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            // handle close button click here
            dismiss();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateTitle() {
        toolbar.setTitle(title+String.valueOf(pager.getCurrentItem()+1)+"/"+cantidad);

    }

}
```

**dialog_contract.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="24dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"/>

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your dialog layout has top padding so that why it has no full height.

`dialog_contract.xml`

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 ...
 android:paddingTop="24dp"
 >
```

Second of all try following [java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) since your code is realy hard to read

> Also when I click the close button of the Dialog it closes not only the dialog, but the activity as well, and goes to the previous activity.

My best guess is that you are not handling menu clicks correctly, try calling

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

from dialogFragmen onCreate

Comment: I solved the problem with the padding but the dialog is still closing the activity

Comment: It is posible that it has something to do with context ?